# YCM g:ycm_semantic_triggers doesn't work

Tags: vim

I written this in my vimrc：

```
  let `g:ycm_semantic_triggers = {'cpp': ['->', '.', '::', 're![a-zA-Z0-9_]'], 'd': ['.', 're![a-zA-Z0-9_]']}`
```

But d or cpp buffers, the semantic completion shows just when I type default triggers, not any character from a-z. Why it doesn't work at all?

I use dutyl,an OmniComplete engine,via DCD to complete D..

Comment: This is a question for YCM's issue tracker.

Comment: My guess is you want a `+` after `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. But honestly I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: `g:ycm_semantic_triggers` does not work as one might expect. It does not check if the text up to the cursor matches, however it checks if the code up to where the current identifier (as defined by [this regex (or one of the language specific regexes)](https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/blob/master/ycmd/identifier_utils.py#L47)) starts. So to start the semantic checker on every character, do something like (this actually starts the checker after only 3 characters):

```
if !exists('g:ycm_semantic_triggers')
    let g:ycm_semantic_triggers = {}
endif
let g:ycm_semantic_triggers.python = ['re!(?=[a-zA-Z_]{3})']
```